# OleDbConnection External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

The following code works fine when trying to open a xls or xlsx file. I am having difficulty opening a file that is downloaded from an external website. The file is formatted as xls and opens in excel, but the content is html based. If I manually open this file and do a File>Save As XLSX then try to open it, the following code works fine.

Does anyone know a way to either open this excel (html based) file using OleDbConnection or some other means?

The error message coming up when opening this file is {"External table is not in the expected format."}

```
                // Connection String to Excel Workbook   
                string  excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Importfile.FullName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";


                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook   
                using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by doing this code snippet.

```
                string htmlFilePathAndName = @"C:\Downloads\Input.xls";
                string newXlsxFilePathAndName = @"C:\Downloads\Output.xlsx";

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xls;
                xls = excel.Workbooks.Open(htmlFilePathAndName);
                xls.SaveAs(newXlsxFilePathAndName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook); // exception
                xls.Close();
```